# Why does xpath query syntax vary in lower version of php

Tags: php, xml, xpath, simplexml

I have been developing on my test server which is PHP 5.5 and used an xpath query of this structure:

```
 $year = $this->xml->xpath("//field[@label='Year']");
 $year[0]['value'];
```

And all works perfect but as sson as I move it to the live server which is php 5.4 all my xpath queries would break. I am just wondering if anyone out there could give me some insight as to why or how to overcome this problem without upgrading php. I am guessing something is not enabled on my live site other than xpath that should be.

Comment: I don't think the PHP version is the reason. I use a lot of Xpath (with DOM) and I never noticed a difference between PHP 5.4 and 5.5. Maybe you live xml is different (has a namespace).

Comment: @ThW I thought of that too, but checked its going to the path. I did echo's to show the path and all and used an alternative syntax on the live server to test one or two instances and it worked. Im just puzzled as to why would i need to make a different syntax for the live or why would the one i did on my test server work perfectly versus the live one

Comment: The most likely cause is a difference in the underlying version of `libxml`, which is the underlying library that all PHP's XML functionality is based on. I think `phpinfo()` should be able to tell you that.

Comment: It is possible that here differences because of the libxml version, but the xpath expression in the question is quite simple - it should show the same behaviour.

Comment: @ThW There were breaking changes in libxml a while ago which caused oddness with particular versions of PHP (PHP was abusing a private property, and eventually lobbied for a public accessor for it). Long before 5.4 and 5.5, but possible that the same thing happened again I guess. Was particularly bad on Gentoo because you could end up with the compile-time lib not matching the runtime one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compare versions of SimpleXml on server and the testing environment. (use phpinfo(); for that)
I would also advice you to step over to [DOMDocument](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) which I have noticed is actually more reliable. Otherwise please post your original xml so we can take a look for possible problems.

Comment: I have made the edit and updated with my original XML

Comment: I just realised my xml had too much information and had to remove it for now

Comment: maybe just post smaller excerpt showing the hierarchy and namespaces if you have any

Comment: SimpleXML and DOM are both based on the same underlying library, so if it is behaving differently in different environments, it's unlikely to make a difference which you use. There are things that SimpleXML can't do (e.g. representing text nodes rather than elements or attributes), but those are unlikely to have changed between versions.

Comment: @IMSoP I agree that both use libxml but I find DOM implementation more complete. Of course SimpleXml is more PHPish. There is a possibility that infomatic have different versions of libxml on the server and his test.

Comment: @infomatic did you enabled PHP error reporting on your server? Do you receive any particular error?

Comment: We did enable PHP error reporting but nothing happened. It turned out the issue was with how we accessed items in php 5.3 vs php 5.4 varied and so the issues were raised from there

Comment: @infomatic I am glad you have resolved your issue :)